# Read uncommitted with update

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions

Consider a table R(A) containing {(1),(2)}.

Suppose transactions

`T1: UPDATE R SET A = 2*A`

`T2: SELECT AVG(A) FROM R`

If transaction T2 executes using "read uncommitted", what are the possible values it returns?

My guess is that it can return either 1.5, 2, 2.5 or 3 because of read uncommitted and the fact that the order of tuples doesn't matter as I understood from the courses.Am I right?

Comment: I agree with your own answer.  Read uncommitted is a "dirty" read, and therefore you might see any permutation of the records in the middle of the update.

Comment: My doubts are about the case when update starts with the second row as I'm not sure it can happen, I am not able to find any official documentation regarding that

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) for `READ UNCOMMITTED`:

> SELECT statements are performed in a nonlocking fashion, but a possible earlier version of a row might be used. Thus, using this isolation level, such reads are not consistent. This is also called a dirty read. Otherwise, this isolation level works like READ COMMITTED.

A dirty read might view the table before, during, or after the update takes place.  This means that, as you pointed out, the apparent average could be 1.5, 2, 2.5, or 3.  Consider:

```
R1 | R2 | average
1  | 2  | 1.5        <-- update not yet started
2  | 2  | 2          <-- update in progress
1  | 4  | 2.5        <-- update still in progress
2  | 4  | 3          <-- update completed
```